# Build a trigger that avoids to update the values of one column

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update, row

I  have a table in PostgretSQL. I want to build a trigger that avoids to update colb1 column. This column has five alternatives: Rea, Can, Loa, Mul, Alm. So the trigger doesn't let upload values from Rea to Can.

I've built this function but this is fail.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
     new.colb1.tabl1 = 'Rea' := old.colb1.tabl1 = 'Can';
     new.colb1.tabl1 = 'Can' := old.colb1.tabl1 = 'Rea';
     RETURN new;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_name ON table1;
  CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE UPDATE ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE example_trigger();
```

I edited my post with changes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_trigger()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.colb1 := OLD.colb1;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER not_changes
 BEFORE UPDATE 
 ON tabl1
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE example_trigger();
```

It's not exactly that I want because I want that the values Loa, Mul and Alm can be update.

Comment: First what column `colb1` or `new.colb.tabl1`? Though `new.colb.tabl1` is not actually a correct syntax. Not sure what you are asking to do? Prevent any update of `colb1` if the current value is either `Rea` or `Can` or allow only a update of those values from one to the other?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited my post because it was a wrong about the name of column. The aim is not allow the update from Rea to Can and  from Can to Rea.

Comment: Well this, `new.colb1.tabl1` is still an incorrect syntax. Also can the `Rea\Can` values be updated to something other then `Rea` or `Can`?

Comment: Yes, the values Rea o Can can be updated by another values.

Comment: You know it won't take long for users to figure out they can do something like Rea --> Loa/Mul/Alm --> Can?

Comment: Yes, they can change the values of Loa, Mul and Alm.

Comment: So what is going to stop them from changing Rea to Can by way of one of the other values? In other words why does it matter that  Rea not become Can or Can not become Rea?

Comment: Because in a first step it cannot go from Rea to Can but in a second step it can, so I would like to know how I can call a value of a column using new and old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification of your function to stop the modification of `colb1` from `Rea` or `Can` to `Can` or `Rea`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION example_trigger()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    IF OLD.colb1 in ('Rea', Can') AND NEW.colb1 IN ('Rea', 'Can') THEN
       NEW.colb1 := OLD.colb1;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This will not stop a user from using an intermediate `UPDATE` to change to one of `Loa/Mul/Alm` and then to either `Rea` or `Can`